# Refreshing script without refresh the html page

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to make it refresh the current song without refreshing the page? I have no idea how to do it. I'm not so in about JS.

```js
var response = $.getJSON('//srvstm.com/api-json/VkZkd1JrMUZPVVZYVkRBOStS', addHTML);

function addHTML(data) {

  // Getting the HTML elements to write in
  var cs = document.getElementById('current-song');
  var g = document.getElementById('genre');

  // Setting data attributes to HTML
  cs.innerHTML = data.musica_atual;
  g.innerHTML = data.genero;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="genre"></span>
  <h1 id="current-song"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the app supposed to know which song is playing? or which event will be triggered when the user changes the song?

Comment: It's a live streaming. The server will tell the script which song is playing.

Comment: I don't think this is a minimal, complete and verifiable question. You need to be a little bit more explicit.

Comment: @wilsotobianco Forget about the function of catching the song information. It's done. Example: I want the script to refresh every 1min without refreshing the page where it is. Got it now? I'm using an iFrame to refresh the script... Is there anyway to refresh it without meta?

Comment: Sure. Have you read about WebSockets? Find documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made a script that refresh a specific content at a div.

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
$('#song').load('http://boomerangfm.xyz/musica.php');
refresh();
});
 
function refresh()
{
 setTimeout( function() {
   $('#song').fadeOut('slow').load('http://boomerangfm.xyz/musica.php').fadeIn('slow');
   refresh();
 }, 30000);
}
```

```html
<div id="song">rádio boomerang fm</div>
```